# Deploying Office 2010 addin

Tags: .net, ms-office, .net-4.0, office-addins

I've created two addins, one is shared addin (for Excel, Word and Outlook) and another one is for Outlook.

They work fine on my machine (where I developed it).

Framework used: 4.0

I've created a 'setup project' throught VS2010 following steps in
[Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx).

When I run setup of it, shared addin runs fine. But the outlook addin does not work.

This is log of 'Event Viewer'

`Event Type: Error
Event Source:   VSTO 4.0
Event Category: None
Event ID:   4096
Date:       4/26/2011
Time:       7:37:52 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   XXX
Description:
Customization URI: file:///C:/Program Files/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX.vsto
Exception:`

******* *Exception Text* *********
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.FrameworkVersionMismatchException: 
  
  

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.SolutionInstaller.Install(ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager clickOnceAddInDeploymentManager, OfficeAddInDeploymentManager officeDeploymentManager, AddInInformation& info)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.SolutionInstaller.ProcessInstallerOperation(ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager clickOnceAddInDeploymentManager, OfficeAddInDeploymentManager officeAddInDeploymentManager, AddInInformation& info)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.SolutionInstaller.ProcessInstallerOperation(ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager clickOnceAddInDeploymentManager, OfficeAddInDeploymentManager officeAddInDeploymentManager, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, IntPtr& executor)

******* *Loaded Assemblies* *********
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3620 (GDR.050727-3600)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.21022.1

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0.dll

System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3614 (GDR.050727-3600)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll

System.Core
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.1 built by: SP

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll

System.AddIn
    Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0
    Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.1 built by: SP

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.AddIn/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.AddIn.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.21022.1

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.21022.1

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v10.0
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.21022.1

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.v10.0.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0
    Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 9.0.30729.4130

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0/9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0.dll

System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll

System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll

System.Deployment
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll

System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll

System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3082 (QFE.050727-3000)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll

System.Security
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3613 (GDR.050727-3600)

### CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

From what I understand, it is not even considering loading addin with framework 4.0

Can anyone tell me where I have done wrong and suggest a solution.

Thank you

Adarsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found solution...

After searching a while found a links to [Office Solution Prerequisites for Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608617.aspx) and [Visual Studio Tools for Office Runtime Installation Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712596.aspx). Installing VSTO 4.0 solved the problem.

Then got new problem ...

> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly XXX.dll.

which got solved after signing the assembly.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Your answer could have been better. You might have described the steps and tools necessary for signing the assembly.

Comment: this.josh - I think the steps & tools for signing assemblies is a separate issue that can be addressed in a separate question "if necessary"