# convert an Excel 2010 addin to a 2007 addin (both VSTO)

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007, add-in, excel-2010

I am currently working on an Excel 2010 add-in which formerly was an Excel 2007 add-in.
Somewhere in the process of switching computers, the add-in was converted i think.

Some of my customers stated that the add-in wasn't working on Excel 2007 anymore so I tried to debug it in a VirtualBox with Excel 2007 and Visual Studio 2010 installed.

Now I get the Error Message:

> You cannot debug or run this project, because the required version of the Microsft Office application is not installed.

I started a new Excel 2007 add-in project and tried to find what the differences are and came up with the idea that it somewhat has to do with the dll's so I changed my 2010 addin until it looked like an 2007 addin.

I still get the error message stating that my project can't be debugged.

Is there anything I could've forgotten to change.

Writing a completely new addin is unfortunately not an option.

These questions haven't helped me so far:

1. [Excel Addin that works on Excel 2007 and 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937891/excel-addin-that-works-on-excel-2007-and-2010)
2. [Deploying Office 2010 addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800141/deploying-office-2010-addin)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get **VS 2010** working with **Office 2007** modify the project file (*.csproj*) so that it will open in Office 2007 and not look for Office 2010 when run (*hence the error message above*).

Here is the project settings change (*Excel example*):

**Source XPath:**

> //Project/ProjectExtensions/VisualStudio/FlavorProperties/ProjectProperties/@DebugInfoExeName

**Old Value (Office 2010):**

> DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\InstallRoot\Path#excel.exe"

**New Value (Office 2007):**

> DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\InstallRoot
>   \Path#excel.exe"

After changing this project setting, when you fire up the debugger (<kbd>F5</kbd>) it will load the Excel 2007 application instead of looking for Excel 2010.

Comment: It looks like the # symbols are just enclosing a registry path -- it looks like it's basically saying "find this path from the registry and append excel.exe to it." -- So I decided to clone my registry settings  from the 12.0 hive into the 14.0 hive and give it a shot. Lo' and behold! It works! -- I can now, with one .sln/.csproj file open and debug the same add-in on my Windows XP/Office 2007 VM as I can on my Windows 7/Office 2010 VM (using VSTO 4.0 of course).

Answer (score 6):

Typically, when I am developing against multiple versions of Office with VSTO Add-ins, I have a project for each version of Office I am targeting.  I put all common code between the projects into a single project (typically the oldest project) and use linked files, I add the common files to the newer projects.  This allows me to write one set of common core code, abstracted from the requirements of each version of Office.  This means I am no longer fighting the different ways VSTO is compiled for each version of Office.  This can be made easier with shared folders and virtual machines, so I can develop and test without multiple computers.  It is by no means graceful, but it works well for me.  This should allow you to develop your VSTO Add-in against both Office 2007 and Office 2010 without much issue.

Comment: so, you have different version of Visual Studios on different VM's, right?

Comment: @T.Todua, at this point, I do not recall. It has been almost 6 years since I worked on a VSTO add-in. I do recall running several VMs for the project, so it would make sense that I had a VM for each environment I was developing for.